# How to return a distinct object inside a Set and sum a common value?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

For example: I have a Set that contains two or more Product instance objects ("they have different amount values")

```
public class Product{

private int id;
private String name;
private String brand;
private Long amount;

// getter and setters
}
```

It's possible to get one single object and sum the amount value using Stream?

Comment: "It's possible to get one single object and sum the amount value" - What's there to sum if you want to get only one object?

Comment: So you want a resulting `Product` object that has an `amount` equal to the sum of `amount`s of `Set<Product>`?

Comment: @Zircon Yes ! the object hame the same id, name, brand... so i want to return an resulting object where amount is equal the sum of all objects.

Comment: You can add  instance variable of type List in Product class and add amount to that list whenever you create an object .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose you have a `Set<Product>` where each product has the same id, name, and brand but different amounts. We could easily create a new `Product`, but doing so with one `Stream` would be superfluous (We could use `reduce` perhaps, but there could be more overhead than just doing the following). Instead, let's create an empty-set-safe solution to your problem:

```
public Product getTotalAsProduct(Set<Product> set) {
    Product newProduct = null;
    Optional<Product> findProduct = set.stream().findFirst();
    if(findProduct.isPresent()) { //No sense in making an object if set is empty
        //Create a new Product with the same id, name, brand
        newProduct = findProduct.get().clone(); //If Cloneable, OR create a constructor that takes a Product and makes a new one, OR make a new Product() and get/set as needed
        long totalAmount = set.stream().mapToInt(Product::getAmount).sum();
        newProduct.setAmount(totalAmount);
    }
    return newProduct; //Null if set was empty
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. it helps me a lot !

Answer (score 2):

`yourSet.stream().mapToInt(Product::getAmount).sum()`

will get you the sum of amounts and you can create a `Product` object setting the  amount to this sum.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !